# Use of 'and' in if statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I need to check thousands of directories for two kinds of files. I have restricted to the index, or idx, to less than four since within that range there would be the two kinds of files that need to be found, the 'jpg' and the '.thmb'. But I need the the if statement to require that those two kinds of files are in the directory. The if statement:

```
if ('.jpg' in val) and ('thmb' in val):
```

works except I keep getting printout through the else statement that data is missing, when it is not true:

```
Data missing W:\\North2015\200\10 200001000031.jpg 0
Data missing W:\\North2015\200\10 200001000032.jpg 1
Data missing W:\\North2015\200\100 200014000001.jpg 0
Data missing W:\\North2015\200\100 200014000002.jpg 1
Data missing W:\\North2015\200\101 200014100081.jpg 2
```

Here is the code below:

```
def missingFileSearch():
    for folder in setFinder():
        for idx,val in enumerate(os.listdir(folder)):
            if idx < 4:
                if ('.jpg' in val) and ('thmb' in val):
                    pass
                else:
                    print'Data missing',folder,val,idx
```

So i am wondering why I am getting the output through the else statement.
Also, this line of code gets hung up:

```
 if val.endswith('.jpg') and ('thmb' in val):
     print'Data is here!',folder,val,idx
```

This is chiefly what I need the code to do.

Comment: `'200001000031.jpg'` does not contain `'thmb'`.  Did you mean your condition to be `if ('.jpg' in val) or ('thmb' in val):` (`or` instead of `and`)?

Comment: Well i think that if i use 'or' instead of 'and' it will satisfy the conditional if either file is in the directory, but not both.

Comment: @hollow_Victory: you are testing *each filename*, not *all filenames*.

Comment: @hollow_Victory: Then for a directory maintain a `thmb_count` and a `jpg_count`.  If `thmb_count` and `jpg_count` are both greater than zero you have a good directory and can break from iteration.  Otherwise you need to keep iterating.  If you have iterated over all the files and still have a zero in one of the counts it's a fail.

Comment: So is the condition that you need *both types* in your directory? So a directory listing `['foo.jpg', 'foo.thmb', 'bar.png']` should match?

Comment: @hollow_Victory: You cannot stop looking after four items (`if idx < 4:`) because iteration order is not guaranteed.  (That's how I'm reading your sentence "I have restricted to the index, or idx, to less than four since within that range there would be the two kinds of files that need to be found, the 'jpg' and the '.thmb'." Did I get that right?)

Comment: That's interesting  Yes i am just trying to look within that indexed range for the files. Otherwise the folders have about 600 files within them. Also, i added some information to the post.

Comment: A quick aside:  You don't need to do `os.chdir(folder)`.  You can do `os.listdir(folder)`.  You need not call it like `os.listdir(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: @Martijin so what do you mean when you say that I am testing each filename, not filenames?

Comment: @ Steven, beautiful solution, thank you

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, so how can I have the code just look within the first four files?

Comment: @hollow_Victory:  There is no first four files because there is no guaranteed order.  Besides, `os.listdir()` fetches the entire list, which is the slowest part of the operation.  Iterating over the result is comparatively fast (disk access speed is much slower than cpu speed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
def missingFileSearch():
    folders_with_missing = []
    for folder in setFinder():
        thmb_found = False
        jpg_found = False
        for fname in os.listdir(folder):
            thmb_found |= 'thmb' in fname
            jpg_found |= fname.endswith('.jpg')
            if thmb_found and jpg_found:
                break # break inner loop, move on to check next folder
        else: # loop not broken
            if not thmb_found and not jpg_found:
                desc = "no thmb, no .jpg"
            elif not thmb_found:
                desc = "no thmb"
            else:
                desc = "no .jpg"
            folders_with_missing.append((folder, desc))
     return folders_with_missing
```

I have tested a slightly modified version of this code (no `setFinder()` function):

```
def missingFileSearch():
    folders_with_missing = []
    for folder in os.listdir(my_dir):
        thmb_found = False
        jpg_found = False
        for fname in os.listdir(os.path.join(my_dir, folder)):
            thmb_found |= 'thmb' in fname
            jpg_found |= fname.endswith('.jpg')
            if thmb_found and jpg_found:
                break # break inner loop, move on to check next folder
        else: # loop not broken
            if not thmb_found and not jpg_found:
                desc = "no thmb, no .jpg"
            elif not thmb_found:
                desc = "no thmb"
            else:
                desc = "no .jpg"
            folders_with_missing.append((folder, desc))
    return folders_with_missing
```

I created four test folders with self explanatory names:

```
>>> os.listdir(my_dir)
['both_thmb_jpg', 'missing_jpg', 'missing_thmb', 'no_files']
```

Then ran the function:

```
>>> missingFileSearch()
[('missing_jpg', 'no .jpg'), ('missing_thmb', 'no thmb'), ('no_files', 'no thmb, no .jpg')]
```

Comment: That works well but the files ending with '.jpg' are still slipping through. So we still have the same problem.

Comment: I tried adding    jpg_end = False    then    jpg_end |= fname.endswith('.jpg')    and it still did the same

Comment: @hollow_Victory: Please explain further.  You have directories that are missing one of `'.jpg'` and `'thmb'` that are not being caught?

Comment: it is still outputting the same .jpg files that it was before. I think the problem is that i cant catch the files that end with .jpg

Comment: Are some actually ending with `'.jpeg'` instead of `'.jpg'`? (Just brainstorming.)

Comment: I tried adding **jpg_end = False** and **jpg_end |= fname.endswith('.jpg')** to the code but still the same issue.

Comment: Not a bad question but no at least not where it is finding them.

Comment: I might have directories that are missing both, but there are certainly some that are missing one or the other and we need to know which ones

Comment: So this is intended to just be the first part of the conditional using the **if - and** statements

Comment: Yes that seems to have done it! So we just needed to kick that else clause out of the for loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: @hollow_Victory: Yes, the `else` is at the same level as the for-loop.  It only runs if the for-loop is not broken.  I edited the code to add a description of which files were missing from the directory.  I also changed the test for `jpg_found` to `jpg_found |= fname.endswith('.jpg')`.

Comment: Well that is some excellent code. Thank you very much. I have learned a lot from this code.

Comment: So does the code iterate through all the files in each directory? Seems too fast to do that.

Comment: It stops iterating when both are found.  It only iterates through all files when one or both filetypes are missing.  But remember, getting the list of filenames from the disk is the slow part.  Iterating over the list is the fast part.  Disk access slow.  CPU fast.  Also, your OS might have cached the results of the `listdir()` if the folders have not been modified.